# Using this to return a value

Tags: java, objective-c, get, return, this

Id like to have similar functionality as this Objective C method in my Java program, however i dont know how to use `this`  in such situation (i know how to use `this` only in constructors). Guess i need to override [] operator?

Objective C

```
   public class MyClass{

     public int this[int i]{

        get{
        return index[i];
        }
     }

    private int[] index;
    }
```

Naive approach would be to write normal method but id prefer to use `this` to save time by not typing `getIndex`.

Java

```
public class MyClass{

     public int getIndex(int i){
        return index[i];
     }

    private int[] index;
    }
```

EDIT: Ok, so i cant override [], thats bad news, thanks anyway guys. Damn you Java.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem in Java code. It will work *as expected*, unless your expectations are different. Note that you cannot override `[]` nor another operator in Java.

Comment: I don't understand your question, `return index[i];` has an *implicit* `this` (in Java). That is, it is `return this.index[i];`

Comment: The top one does not look like valid Objective-C syntax. Did you mean C#?

Comment: it should be valid Objective C syntax, i just dont want to keep writing getIndex and only pass in the value (guess, by using overridden operator).

Comment: You're looking for syntax sugar. You cannot do that in Java.

Comment: @GiomePoolGuy Your "Objective-C" code is absolutely not Objective-C. Not even close.

Comment: `this` has applications outside a constructor too...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override operators in Java. This means, you cannot override `+`, `-`, `[]` nor another kind of operator. Instead, you should create methods that will perform the desired behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use this to create a getter in Java. The best solution is:

```
public int getIndex(int i){
    return index[i];
}
```

Comment: You can write `return this.index[i]`. This question is unclear. By the way, seems more like OP tries to override `[]` operator, so it can do `MyClass myClass = ...; System.out.println(myClass[0]);`.